# IBM Mobilefirst application remove my plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, hybrid-mobile-app, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

im working on hybrid application using IBM mobilefirst, once i rebuilt my project on Eclipse for several time, my java plugins are gone and also my setting on xml for android is override. Are there any way to prevent this? Or what's the root cause of that?

Answer (score 0):

If you made these changes in the generated Android project, then you need to make sure to copy them back to the MobileFirst project, otherwise upon the next build the generated project will indeed be overwritten, and the changes will be lost.